# Unified common editor icons

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

[image]

Now this might sound like it's not a big deal but I was just passing by [ux stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) , and  I tried to post something in there . The insert link icon is different than the other stackexchnage sites that I'm using (mostly stackoverflow) , that it took me a second to look for it .
I guess it would be a great idea to unify the common icons all over stackexchange .

I'm just saying **it would be great to have a good UX in  the UX site**.

Comment: i did search though . but couldn't find it .

Comment: @JoachimSauer it's not a duplicate , the question over there is about if they are going to change or not . im saying that they should be the same all over the network .

Comment: yes, the question is different, but the answer probably isn't: That's part of the per-site design for each site and chances are that it's not going to be changed for consistencies sake. Consistency of the design of a given question is *more important* than consistency of editor icons over the entire stack exchange network.

Comment: @JoachimSauer i get your point regarding consistency . but this wansn't a part of the answer of the other question , and i still think this is no duplicate . ;)